# Error while installing discord.py saying i need VS build tools

Tags: python, discord.py

I get this error even though I have install VS build tools!!  I dont know what to do as I have already installed VS build tools. I have tried everything possible. Doing this in vs code and everything else. I have searched around to no avail. What should i do now?

```
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
Failed to build multidict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: _I have already installed VS build tools_ After installing, did you add them to your `PATH` environment?

Answer (score 0):

So hi.
In the error, you can see that it says  **error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools"**
And you can see that there is a link to download a higher version in front of it.[this link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)

Another solution is to update pip.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Or update your wheel

```
python -m pip install --upgrade wheel
```